# Nuget Error Ocurred

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm having trouble to put Nuget to work properly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, I can't see any package in the "Browse" tab. It keeps loading for some minutes and then throws the error: "Error ocurred"

I can access this normally via browser:

- https://www.nuget.org/
  And I don't use proxy

Anybody knows what that can be?

See Below:

[image]

Comment: Does any operation work in Package Manager Console ?

Comment: No, it gives the error: "Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: try to add a PackageId property to src\common.props 

<PackageId>$(MSBuildProjectName)</PackageId>

Comment: added, but still the same.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2239#issuecomment-193208925)?

Comment: Have you try to close Visual Studio, rename nuget.config file in the %appdata%/Nuget, then re-open Visual Studio and open Package Manager console. What is the log after click "Show errors in output"?

Comment: the nuget started to work again, without me doing anything. From time to times it starts the problem all over again, so I am waiting it bugs for me to follow the sugestions of you guys. Thank you for while :)